# Rails asset pipeline and digest values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Does anyone know how exactly the asset digest value is calculated? If I have two JS files which contain various other included JS scripts then will each file maintain the same digest hash if none of the inner scripts have been changed? Or is a new digest value calculated each time the assets:precompile operation is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grabbed from [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

> When a filename is unique and based on its content, HTTP headers can
>   be set to encourage caches everywhere (whether at CDNs, at ISPs, in
>   networking equipment, or in web browsers) to keep their own copy of
>   the content. When the content is updated, the fingerprint will change.
>   This will cause the remote clients to request a new copy of the
>   content. This is generally known as cache busting.
>
> The technique that Rails uses for fingerprinting is to insert a hash
>   of the content into the name, usually at the end. For example a CSS
>   file global.css could be renamed with an **MD5 digest of its contents**

Comment: So is a simple md5_file() operation performed on the final file after all the merging and compression is performed? That md5 value ends up being the digest for the file correct?

Comment: According to the docs, yes. You can refer to [another guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#in-production) for more details.

Answer (score 45):

The accepted answer is not quite true. We build static assets for our staging, demo and production servers, and the same asset is given different digest values in each case.

It turns out that the Rails environment is also being taken into consideration. Sprockets creates the digest as follows:

```
# Sprockets::Environment::initialize
@digest_class = ::Digest::MD5

# Sprockets::Base::digest
@digest ||= digest_class.new.update(VERSION).update(version.to_s)

# Sprockets::Base::file_digest(path)
digest.file(path.to_s)

# Sprockets::Asset::initialize
@digest = environment.file_digest(pathname).hexdigest
```

Rails hooks into Sprockets as follows:

```
# Sprockets::Railtie
app.assets = Sprockets::Environment.new(app.root.to_s) do |env|
  env.version = ::Rails.env + "-#{config.assets.version}"
  ...
end
```

So rails is creating a Sprockets environment that has a version equal to the Rails environment, and Sprockets uses the version when creating the digest class.

Comment: Thanks for this one. I had to change the digest on my assets to invalidate Cloudflare cache without changing the assets files content. Changing the config.assets.version from "1.0" to "1.1" changes the signature ;)

Comment: What version of Rails is this true for? It would be good to have an update for Rails 5 if it has changed