# Find digested image file name by original filename from public/assets in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Is there a way in rails 4 to find fingerprinted file name which in public/assets (eg.Alert-a4dd61e5de5036fef9ebcc6488db849a.png) by original file name (eg. Alert.png)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails asset pipeline and digest values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10021784/rails-asset-pipeline-and-digest-values)

Comment: you asking for the manifest file? public/assets/manifest.yml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Sprockets/Asset#digest_path`](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/rails/sprockets/Sprockets/Asset#digest_path-instance_method)

```
asset = Rails.application.assets.find_asset("Alert.png")
=> #<Sprockets::Asset:3fe75fb2a4e0 "file:///path/to/app/assets/images/Alert.png?type=image/png&id=058defbe2f1fc00236008c87d63171927c34d2b314c3a7cb55390744cc1d116c">

filename = asset.digest_path
=> "Alert-184c97a008b89f10892a7ba1eb5f2e9e60e40c977244f934664be3e4fce056a8.png"
```